# Changing value of a pointer, from a pointer of pointer , which pointing to an array of structure as an object in structure

Tags: arrays, c, object, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Car {
    char *merk  ;
    int price   ;
}   car[3]  ;

//    content of the array of structure
void declare(){

    car[0].merk = "toyota";
    car[0].price =   20000;

    car[1].merk = "nissan";
    car[1].price =   30000;

    car[2].merk = "bmw";
    car[2].price =   100000;
}

int main(){
    declare();
    struct Car *pCar ;  
    pCar = car ;    /* pointer pointing to car */
    struct Car **ppCar ;
    ppCar = &pCar ; /* pointer pointing to pCar */

    return 0    ;
}
```

// how to change value of pCar, indirectly from ppCar ?
// can i change it from *ppCar ?

Comment: "can i change it from *ppCar ". Yes, why do you think you may not be able to?

Comment: `pCar = car` -> `pCar = &car`

Comment: @Jabberwocky `car` is actually a `struct Car` array. I missed that initially too.

Comment: @kaylum , i just confused how to do it, but i'm pretty sure it;s able to

Comment: this code :
(*ppCar)++ ;
works, i solved i friends , thank you :)